# Give a function "block" a different background color in Vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like for function blocks to have a different background color than the rest of IDE in vscode. Is it possible?

```
function hello(){

}
```

// normal background color here

```
function hello2(){
}
```

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oderwat.indent-rainbow ? would you accept that as an answer? if not, why not?

Comment: I would like the whole block to be the same color.

Comment: search the market place for `block`, it has an extension with that in the name

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't really work as I would like. It feels buggy. @rioV8

Comment: there is another one that colors blocks, it is not the one linked by starball